# PowerApps Portal vs regular PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

I developed a PowerApps application, but each user would have to pay $10 a month making it not economically viable (I had hoped for some kind of run-time license at a much lower rate).  So I talked to a MS sales guy who said I should switch to PowerApps Portal.
However, it seems to be a completely different product.  I have drop-down boxes, radio buttons, command buttons all with PowerApps type code behind them.  Also datasources (Azure SQL database, Excel workbook). And 3 or 4 screens that the user is directed to (based on command buttons pressed).
Anyway, none of this functionality seems to be found in PowerApps Portal from what I can see.
Am I missing something?
If so, just posting me a link to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

You are right. PowerApps and PowerApps portals are unrelated & not having very much in common.

**PowerApps (Canvas app)** is meant for low-code/no-code for quickly building apps by citizen developers, using 200+ connectors for different datasources. Applicable for AAD users, will be available shortly for external users as well. This has per user per app, or unlimited app access kinda licensing models.

**PowerApps (Model-driven)** is Dynamics 365 CRM under the hood, with SQL Azure as backend. Strictly for AAD users only. This has module based licensing (Sales, Service, Field Service, Talent, Project mgmt, etc)

**PowerApps Portals** (previously Dynamics 365 portals & Adxstudio) - Main purpose is to build portal solutions (B2B or B2C), like website for Employees, Customers, Partners, etc provisioned on top of **Model-driven PowerApps platform**. This can leverage external logins like Google, Facebook, Windows Live (Microsoft), etc.

This has even tricky licensing model - [Refer official page](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/portals/) and the gist below explains crisply:

> For external users, Microsoft will differentiate between anonymous and authenticated users. Access by authenticated users will be charged on a "per log-in" basis that has raised some confusion among people on Twitter. A log-in is defined as a twenty-four hour period of access by a single authenticated user, and one hundred such log-ins will cost $200 and will be charged on a monthly basis.

[Read more](https://msdynamicsworld.com/story/microsoft-reveals-powerapps-portals-pricing-and-licensing-approach%E2%80%99s)