# powerapps model driven vs canvas

Tags: powerapps

We are in need to create mobile version of our web site in PowerApps. We are novice and need to decide what to select: Canvas or Model-Driven. Our web site has 2 CRUD pages working with SQL. One page has 4 combo boxes with SQL data where user can type or select value. Another page is grid where user type value in cell and we do JavaScript logic to fill other cells or change other cells background color. Please suggest what we need to choose.

Thanks

Comment: Read my answer for a clear picture - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59062331/7920473 more than development, you will find out that you have to consider other things.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Understand that a PowerApps is primarily used for line-of-business apps. Building a **public-facing**, mobile version of your (organization?) website is not doable in either Model-driven nor Canvas PowerApps. If you want a publicly accessible website, you'll need to create it as a PowerApps Portal.

If you are creating an **internal**, mobile version of your organizations website, then you need to consider licensing and data volume.

1. Want to pay for per-user licensing (@ ~$10/user/month retail)?

- **No?** Then use Sharepoint as a data source with a Canvas app (easiest)
- **Yes?** Then use SQL as a data source with a Canvas app

2. If you expect high volumes of data, you don't want to use Sharepoint

- It gets real buggy when list size > 5k records
- Only option at that point is to pay for licensing for each user or develop a Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is ideal for mobile platforms and you can use it with SQL. You will need to use PowerFX for your logics instead of JavaScript.